# Speed up SQL NOT IN query MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a query as part of my process, that I execute hundreds of times in a loop.

Initially, Table A contains all records (20mil).  Table B contains 0 records.
Primary key in both tables ID
the I execute:

```
select * from table A where a.ID not in (select ID from table b) limit 10000
##magic stuff in python
insert everything to table B, once again, .
```

Initially, the query runs super fast, but after Nth loop (100th+), size of table B increases, to the point where I it takes a bit of time to perform the NOT IN operation.

Does anyone have recommendations on how I can speed up the query?
- So far, I've tweaked the default mysql bugger to be 1.5gbs (ids are pretty small INTs, so that should be enough).

**Caveats:**

1) One way to do this would be to remove * from table A after I've processed them.  However, I want to keep table A in tact.

... only method I could think of I adding another column to table A (which I'd index) called 'PROCESSED'... then update that column with a second query once the records have been processed/posted, but I was hoping there was an easier solution.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Please explain the purpose of `B`.

Comment: purpose of B is to know what has already been processed.  Note - This process will be executed every few days, and ID's may not come in sequentially - IE... First run i may have 2,3,5 ... process that, then two days later 1 and 4 will come, so i'll have to process those :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to look at every row in `A` and do something with it, there is a much more efficient way.  (It seems that `B` is merely there to see what you have already processed.)

The reason for it getting slower is that it has to do more work as it gets farther into `A` -- namely skipping over the rows it has processed.  A `processed` flag might suffer the same malady.

So...

Walk through `A` processing chunks as you go.  Then remember where you left off so that the next 10000 will be right there, no searching.  I discuss that in more detail with an eye to `DELETEing`, but it can be adapted for other purposes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks  With that, `B` is unnecessary.

**Partitioning**

If you are thinking about partitioning the data by months, I have to ask you "Why?".  Here are some answers:

- For performance?  You won't get any.
- For rapid deletion of "old" data?  This is a good use case, but be sure to use `PARTITION BY RANGE(...)` and include the year, too.  More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Comment: this could work as well.  Not could, but would.  
What did end up doing is increasing the chunk size by 100x , and the query seems to work just as fast.  In fact, I'm doing a test run again, just to see how fast all records get processed - looks like its going to take 15 mins vs original 3 hours.  So I am happy with that

Comment: @FlyingZebra1 - I prefer chunks of 100 to 1000 for a variety of reasons.  And, as you say, the chunk size does not matter to performance -- it is "linear" or "O(N)".  Yours was "quadradic" or "O(N^2)".

Comment: to summarize:  what i noticed is that pulling 10k records using the original query, takes roughly same amount of time as pulling 1M records...  which is something I can afford to do in this case, since I'm not pulling in much data.

One thing about this process is that the IDs aren't going to come in sequentially/be processed sequentially, since I will need to run this query every few days.  So it may be worthwhile to stick to the process I have + maybe foreign keys?

Comment: @FlyingZebra1 -- if the purpose is to _re_process all the data every few days, then this chunking should work.  If you need to _avoid_ reprocessing, then consider the `processed` flag, but still walk through the table in chunks -- 10K chunks may find only a few hundred "new" (`processed = 0`) items next week, but it still works reasonably efficiently.

Comment: to be honest, increasing the limit by 100x is good enough for my needs, since the data isn't going to gow that much from week to week, and processing time of 10 mins every week is good enough :)  But I do appreciate the input!

Comment: @FlyingZebra1 Could you post your AFTER query?  Thanks

Comment: @WilsonHauck A month later, with more data, I ended up implementing a few fields, signifying whether something has been 'processed' (0/1), indexing those fields, then adding an update statement at the end of each loop.  It was a bit more work, but definitely works fast.
I guess next up - figure out how partitioning works in mysql, and split the data up into monthly partitions or something of that sort.

Comment: @FlyingZebra1 - Partitioning? -- I added to my answer.

Comment: @FlyingZebra1 Any chance you will post your CURRENT solution that runs faster than the original with SHOW CREATE TABLE (tbl_name's) involved?